# Adding rows sequentially with generated DateTime values return

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using `Entity Framework 6.1.2` with Code First and am using a Repository to add multiple rows to the database.

Every row is added in an atomic context. The class i am dealing with has a property of type `DateTime`, which is set to `DateTime.Now` before it is saved to the database.

Later, this property is used to check if only the last row is being worked on.

This works on my local machine. When using Unit Tests, there are several objects added to the context at once and then tested if my business logic makes the correct assumptions based on the described property.

However, the dates are all the same, not even a millisecond difference. I cant really add code here, since i cannot even reproduce it on my local machine, but i assume that it has something to do with rounding that happens when the DateTime is written to database.

**Update**

Solved the problem by stuffing my DateTime into SqlDateTime

```
new SqlDateTime(date).Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably encountering this issue due to different accuracy precision between .Net DateTime and SqlDateTime. Have you tried converting the date to SqlDateTime prior to adding to EF?

SqlDateTime has an accuracy of 3.33 ms (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime(v=vs.110).aspx)
whereas DateTime has an accuracy of 3 ms (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

You could omit the second part (omitting the ms part alone won't do as you might have a case where the ms round to the nearest second).

Comment: I have indeed fixed this error by stuffing the date into the proper SqlDate